# How do I add Android TV libraries to Cordova project?

Tags: android, cordova, androidx, leanback

I'm trying to add Android TV support to an existing Cordova project (made with Construct 3 game development software). I'm following this official guide:
https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start

I made the required changes to the manifest, but the guide also mentions adding these TV libraries, and I am not sure how and where to do this:

```
androidx.leanback.app
androidx.leanback.database
androidx.leanback.graphics
etc.
```

I added `<preference name="AndroidXEnabled" value="true" />` to the config.xml, but it's probably not enough.

Also, I don't know if it's related, but when I try to build the project, I get the following error:

```
Android resource linking failed
D:\Cordova\s3\platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:12:9-17:20: AAPT: error: resource style/Theme.Leanback (aka com.mygame.name:style/Theme.Leanback) not found.
```

**EDIT:** Ok, I think I solved both problems, but not sure if this is the right solution.
I added this line to \platforms\android\app\build.gradle into dependencies section:

```
implementation("androidx.leanback:leanback:1.2.0-alpha01")
```

Answer (score 1):

I added this line to \platforms\android\app\build.gradle into dependencies section:
implementation("androidx.leanback:leanback:1.2.0-alpha01")

The app now builds and works on TV.